# Is there a way to get the <div> class attribute to apply to different elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm wondering if there is a way to style different elements with the same class using a `div` tag. I know that this works:

```
<head>
<style>
.intro { color: red }
</style>
</head>

<body><div class="intro">

<p>This should be red.</p>

</div></body>
```

And that this also works:

```
<head>
<style>

h1.intro { color: blue }
p.intro { color: red }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="intro">This should be blue.</h1>
<p class="intro">This should be red.</p>

</body>
```

So given this you would think something like this would work:

```
<head>
<style>

h1.intro { color: blue }
p.intro { color: red }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="intro">

<h1>This should be blue.</h1>
<p>This should be red.</p>

</div>

</body>
```

But no luck. Is there a way to do this? Or should I give up and type it out the long way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `So given this you would think something like this would work` – no it shouldn't. `p.intro` means match any `<p class="intro">`. You are overcomplicating things. Should be `.intro p` instead – which means match every `<p>` inside the `.intro`. Learn any CSS convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make your sample work:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>

    .intro h1 { color: blue }
    .intro p { color: red }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="intro">

    <h1>This should be blue.</h1>
    <p>This should be red.</p>

    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

with ".intro" you identify the container and then specify the inner element style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
.intro h1 { color: blue }
.intro p { color: red }
```

, since the `h1` and the `p` element are children of your `.intro` div:

```css
.intro h1 {
  color: blue
}

.intro p {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">

  <h1>This should be blue.</h1>
  <p>This should be red.</p>

</div>
```

Or you use classes on the elements themselves:

```css
.intro1 { color: blue }
.intro2 { color: red }
```

```html
<div>

<h1 class="intro1" >This should be blue.</h1>
<p class="intro2" >This should be red.</p>

</div>
```